# How to detect a spoofed email with Outlook Web Access?

Tags: email, email-spoofing, outlook

I am specifically asking about Outlook Web Access (browser based Outlook), and not for any other email service or program.

Within Outlook Web Access, is there a way to tell whether or not an email was spoofed? For example, if I receive an email from "boss@company.com", how can I be sure that the email is from "company.com" and not spoofed?

There is an option in Outlook to direct all messages from outside the organization to the junk folder, but I found that this feature is not reliable. Spoofed messages still get through.

Comment: Is looking at the email-headers an option?

Comment: @VipulNair yes, if it is possible to do so in Outlook. However, I don't think there is a way to do that without opening the email first (which poses a security risk).

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion that opening a mail is a security risk?

Comment: @VipulNair Email may contain an image or other link that gets fetched by outlook when opening the email and this gives information to the attacker. AFAICT there is no way to access the email headers without opening the email first in outlook online.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta what kind of information?

Comment: @VipulNair That you have opened the email and are thus a candidate target for a phishing or a more sophisticated spearphishing attack

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta thats it?I dont think thats a huge issue.

Comment: @SamSmith https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135884/why-is-it-dangerous-to-open-a-suspicious-email